# Homebrew error when updating git

Tags: git, homebrew

I just got Homebrew.
When I run `brew doctor` I get the following ouput...

```
Warning: An outdated version of Git was detected in your PATH.
Git 1.7.10 or newer is required to perform checkouts over HTTPS from GitHub.
Please upgrade: brew upgrade git
```

So I run `brew upgrade git` and simply get `Error: git not installed`

Is there an option for getting more verbose error output? Or should I upgrade git outside of Homebrew?

Cheers

Comment: I have the same issue, except that i absolutely use git on both cli and github-for-mac. `brew install git` throws errors: `make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/config.h', needed by 'perl.mak'.  Stop.` will try re-installing from the native installer.

Answer (score 13):

Run

```
$ brew install git
```

You probably have an older version of Git (perhaps installed with Xcode) elsewhere on your system.

Answer (score 2):

The command `brew upgrade git` attempts to upgrade your existing Homebrew installation of Git, but you don't have one.

You *could* use Homebrew to install a current version of Git, but you would probably be better off using the plain old installer (available at http://git-scm.com/download/mac).  That way, you shouldn't run into any `$PATH` confusion or other problems that might arise from having multiple Git installations.

Comment: I did update using the old installer like you suggested but it apparently simply installed yet another version of git instead of replacing the old one to which the path still points to. What could I do now?

Comment: with the installer comes an uninstall script that removes older versions. i went this route and homebrew is not complaining any more (of course my other git apps need some attention now).